# Autoload CSV for batch printing labels (Brother P-touch Editor v5.1)

Tags: automation, csv, label-printer

My goal is to automatically print shipping labels for an e-commerce website based on periodically created .csv-files.

I have the .csv-files ready. I also have the shipping label template ready in P-Touch Editor. This application allows to connect to a 'database' (in the form of a .csv-file in this case) and populate fields.

At this point I need to automate the process of opening the label template in P-Touch Editor and connect to the latest .csv-file, then print all the labels. Since I am running OS X, Applescript seemed like the obvious choice initially, but P-Touch Editor appears not to support it. I am stuck and looking for a way to communicate with either P-Touch Editor or create labels automatically in a different application and print from there.

As an alternative, I am considering exporting an html page from my e-commerce website and setup proper page dimensions and page-breaks, then print this.

Does anyone have a similar situation to mine or know a solution? In the end the goal is to never have to manually print labels and simply pick up the stack twice a day and start packing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Applescript Solution:

While Brothers' "P-touch Editor" (v5.1) does not support Applescript, you can use the "System Events" application to tell a process to perform tasks. This works by manipulating the GUI, personally I do not like this approach, but it works.

In order to do what is stated in the question, I have written the following Applescript (this has only been tested in a fairly controlled environment on OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite), using P-touch Editor v5.1, and Applescript v2.4).

```
# set the location of the 'database'

set prepareShipments to "/some/dir/list.csv"

# set variables to identify the label the needs to be printed and the list containing the dataset
set templateDir to "/some/other/dir"
set templateName to "someTemplate"
set templateExt to ".lbx"
# open the template, my default application for this filetype is "P-touch Editor"
do shell script "open " & templateDir & templateName & templateExt
# "System Events" will tell its process "P-touch Editor" to perform our desired tasks
tell application "System Events"
    #hold-up while application is loading and set it to the 'frontmost' or active process
    repeat until frontmost of process "P-touch Editor" is true
        tell process "P-touch Editor" to set frontmost to true
    end repeat
    
    # actually start telling P-touch Editor what to do:
    tell process "P-touch Editor"
        # wait for template to open..
        repeat until exists window templateName
        end repeat
        
        # 'connect...' to database, if already connected (then the menu item is not clickable), choose to 'change...' the database instead
        click menu item "Connect..." of menu "Database" of menu item "Database" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        click menu item "Change..." of menu "Database" of menu item "Database" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        
        # hold-up until dialog window exists
        repeat until exists window "Open Database"
        end repeat
        
        # enter the location of the new 'database'
        set value of text field 1 of window "Open Database" to prepareShipments
        # my csv file does not contain headers. So uncheck the 'Header Row Contains Field Names' box
        if value of checkbox "Header Row Contains Field Names" of window "Open Database" is 1 then
            click checkbox "Header Row Contains Field Names" of window "Open Database"
        end if
        
        # just keep swimming...
        click button "Next" of window "Open Database"
        click button "OK" of window "Open Database"
        
        # database is connected to template; time to print
        click menu item "Print..." of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        click button "Print" of sheet 1 of window templateName
        
        # printjob has been issued, time to wrap up. Close the window
        click menu item "Close" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        # changes have been made, give some time for the 'save changes' dialog to pop up.
        delay 0.5
        # if it did pop up, tell it to not save the changes (using short-cut '[cmd] + [down arrow] + d')
        if exists window 1 then
            if name of window 1 = templateName then keystroke "d" using command down
        end if
        # do a regular quit, we do not know if any other unsaved windows are open, or whether we want to keep those changes, so do not force any 'do not save' actions.
        click menu item "Quit P-touch Editor" of menu "P-touch Editor" of menu bar item "P-touch Editor" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell

#now that printjob is finished and P-touch Editor is quit, add some additional script for cleaning the inventory, moving printed .csv files to archived folder.
```

See the comments in above script to see what it does. Of course this could be improved upon in order to account for more cases, but I will personally run this in a controlled environment. Most likely a headless Mac Mini that is connected to the printer.

### Alternative answer (more appropriate for Windows users):

As @Hannu mentioned, there is a 'Labeling SDK' available on [Brother's website](http://www.brother.com/product/dev/label/bpac/index.htm) called 'b-PAC SDK'. It would technically allow for automatic database connection using one of the methods described in [this document](http://download.brother.com/pub/com/dev/pdf/bpac_webapplication_eng.pdf), but requires a windows-environment. Since my webserver is run on Linux and my clients all run OS X, I am unable to further test this at the moment.
It does seem to be a more 'elegant' solution, however. As I do not like scripting to manipulate GUI. It seems very inefficient.

Comment: Can you run the Windows solution in a VM or compatibility layer (e.g., Wine or CrossOver)?

Comment: Possibly, probably. I do not have access to these tools, however. I am currently working on an Applescript solution through GUI scripting. Something I found out about a while ago. If I get it working I will post it when it's useful to others as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a label template and upload it to the printer. In the template you can define IDs for each field (text, bar code, etc). Next you can print directly by the network and send for each ID the right data from your website. The printer then fills the data into the template and prints it out. If have done so on my iPad to automate printing labels from a custom app. For network printing I used the QL-720NW via WLAN. The printing is then done with RAW on port 9100 to push the data. The printing commands are explained in the ESC/P command reference handbook.

Answer (score 0):

The P-touch editor should be able to do this by itself, at least v5.x that I'm using (Windows).
I often have an Excel sheet Autofilter list as the source database.

You open the database,
then insert fields into the label,
then off you go.

As I do not have a access to these at home I cannot create a more detailed guide.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I am indeed able to connect to the database when I open the application manually, go to the menu and click all the clicky bits. The data is loaded and I could print all the labels.
However, my goal is to have a script do all this for me, so I can get home from work and have all the labels printer for me already.

Comment: If you save that label, then all you have to do next time is make sure the database is available and open the label - then print.

Comment: I understand that the process is fairly automated as is. But it still requires me to sit down behind my computer, open up the label template, `File` > `Database...` > `change...`, navigate to the file and print.
That's what I aim to get rid of.

Comment: There is an SDK (or example files) for VBA on Brother's webpage - it was some time ago that I had a look. You might be lucky and find a suitable variant for your situation.

Comment: Thank you @Hannu. I found it, but it's a windows-only application. Therefore it's not especially useful in my situation. Still, I have included it in my answer.